# What EEA countries are lenient towards EEA citizens bringing their non-EEA parents?

Tags: germany, eu, family, europe, non-citizens

I am a German citizen earning enough to support both myself and my non-EEA mother (who is dependent on my remote support). Unfortunately, the law makes it as good as impossible for me to bring her to Germany.

Now, if I find a job in another EEA country and move, [Directive 2004/38/EC](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/residence/family-residence-rights/parents/index_en.htm) would (at least in theory) allow me to bring my mother. I've spent several days searching through immigration boards and it looks like in some countries (e.g. the UK and Ireland) the chances of my mother's application not getting refused are quite slim.

Are there any EEA countries that are rather lenient towards EEA citizens bringing their non-EEA parents?

Comment: The only real opportunity for discretion is evaluating whether your mother is dependent on you.  If that is obviously the case then it should not matter which country you choose.  My mother in law got an EEA family permit from the UK on the basis of fairly slim evidence of dependence, but that was for a visit.

Comment: Hi Leo. I am also facing the same problem where as in my case I am on a blue card in Germany and not a citizen. Let me know if you find something on this topic. As far as my research, Norway seems to be a country which seems to have a defined process with regard to this and allows to bring dependent parents. I'm still researching.

Comment: @mayooran Norway seems to have a special law regarding citizens of Nordic countries. So unfortunately it doesn't apply in our cases.

Comment: @Leo can you check here? https://www.udi.no/en/want-to-apply/family-immigration/family-immigration-with-norwegian-or-nordic-citizen/ From what I see, we can do that with a work permit?